# Getting llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit error

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc, compiler-errors

I have no idea how to debug this, and I've been banging my head against the wall for hours. Here is the error I got:

```
Ld /Users/MyAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAC-goimuvevceqxowccylmmpcflbtvz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TAC.app/TAC normal i386
    cd "/Users/MyAccount/Desktop/Programming Stuff/iOS Programming/XCode 4/TAC"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/MyAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAC-goimuvevceqxowccylmmpcflbtvz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0/Symbols/usr/lib "-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/usr/lib" -F/Users/MyAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAC-goimuvevceqxowccylmmpcflbtvz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-F/Users/MyAccount/Desktop/Programming Stuff/iOS Programming/XCode 4/TAC" -filelist /Users/MyAccount/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAC-goimuvevceqxowccylmmpcflbtvz/Build/Intermediates/TAC.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/TAC.build/Objects-normal/i386/TAC.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40300 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework Security -framework CoreMotion -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework MobileCoreServices -lxml2.2 -lz.1.2.5 -o /Users/MasonSilber/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TAC-goimuvevceqxowccylmmpcflbtvz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TAC.app/TAC

ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0/Symbols/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file
ld: in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Any help is really appreciated. I would normally spend more time working on my own to solve the problem, but I really have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building against Simulator then you explicitly need to add i386 as an valid architecture. Also check under platform you have "iphonesimulator". Just click on your project file and it will reveal Build settings in the right side editor. You will find these settings there. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is saying that there is a missing 32 bit Intel architecture in the relevant libraries.

I would ask why you are persisting with GCC 4.2 when LLVM 2.0 is the default compiler now and gcc development has been shut down (at Apple)

Have a go at switching to LLVM 2.1 and see if the problem remains.

You really need to be asking about this bug on the Apple Dev forums if it's important to you to use GCC as iOS 5 and XCode 4.2 are NDA

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add any library.try to add a directory that what you have missed.It resolve this issue.